# silverlight column chart on datagrid tooltip

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I need to create column chart in silverlight datagrid tooltip based on the datagrid column value.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Magz

Answer (score 0):

I did this task using the below post.
try this http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2010/03/03/Custom-tool-tips-in-Silverlight-charts.aspx